# Apply custom function to any dataset with common name

Tags: r, function, dplyr, apply, ranking

I have a custom function that I want to apply to any dataset that shares a common name.

```
common_funct=function(rank_p=5){ 
  df =  ANY_DATAFRAME_HERE[ANY_DATAFRAME_HERE$rank <rank_p,]
  return(df)
}
```

I know with common functions I could do something like below to get the value of each.

```
apply(mtcars,1,mean)
```

But what if I wanted to do :

```
apply(any_dataset, 1, common_funct(anyvalue))
```

How would I pass that along?

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars$rank = dense_rank(mtcars$mpg)
iris$rank = dense_rank(iris$Sepal.Length)
```

Now how would I go about applying my same function to both values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you question, I would suggest putting you data frames into a list and apply over it. So

```
## Your example function
common_funct=function(df, rank_p=5){ 
  df[df$rank <rank_p,]
}

## Sanity check
common_funct(mtcars)
common_funct(iris)
```

Next create a list of the data frames

```
l = list(mtcars, iris)
```

and use `lapply`

```
lapply(l, common_funct)
```